# fourier series representation

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

Find the Fourier series with period $2$ of

$$f(x) = -x,\qquad-1<x<1$$

so I find that $a_0$ and $a_n$ both are $0$ since odd functions
so the Fourier series is on the form: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(n\pi x)$$
so the question is: how do I find $b_n$? I know the formula but I am not sure how to solve the definite integral which is.
$$-\int_{-1}^{1} x\sin(n\pi x)\,dx$$

thanks for any help!

Comment: Partial integration, say...?

Comment: hmm what? :D I think its integration by parts etc so if I have u=x and dv=sin(n*pi*x) I get v= (-1/n*pi) * cos(n*pi*x) and du=1 but now idk what? and idk if what I alredy wrote is correct :(

Comment: use MathJax (LaTeX) to write mathematics here, otherwise it's very hard to understand you: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u=x\;,\;\;u'=1\\v'=\sin n\pi x\;,\;\;v=-\frac1{n\pi}\cos n\pi x$$

so

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1x\sin n\pi x\,dx=\left.-\frac x{n\pi}\cos n\pi x\right|_{-1}^1+\frac1{n\pi}\int\limits_{-1}^1\cos n\pi x\,dx=\\$$

$$=-\frac2{n\pi}\cos n\pi+\left.\frac1{n^2\pi^2}\sin n\pi x\right|_{-1}^1=(-1)^{n+1}\frac2{n\pi}$$

and etc....

Comment: hmm I still dont understand how you got the last line? specially (-2)/(n*pi) * cos(n*pi)? but I guess the second expression is just 1/n*pi multiplied with the integral cos(n*pi*x)?

Comment: @gger234 : $\;\cos n\pi=(-1)^n\;$ ....and use MathJax, please!

Comment: well.. I still dont understand what you mean. I hate this stuff lol.. I get what you're saying but I still dont know how you get these expressions.

Comment: @gger234, didn't you understand what I wrote in my last comment?? You studied trigonometry, right?

Comment: well I get what you wrote in your last comment, but I dont get how that make that expression equal to the series expression thingymajig on the last line, and I also dont get where 2 is from?

Comment: What **exactly** is that you don't understand, @gger234 ? The very last equality sign? One before the last one? Something else...? Did you already sit to check and repeat what I wrote in my answer? Did you evaluate the first summand in the right hand in the line before the last one?

Comment: I dont understand the how you get either of the sides of the 2 last equality signs :O

Comment: Did you make the calculations *by yourself* already, @gger234 ??

Comment: yeah I managed the first line, but after that I dont know wher eyou get any of the expressions from

Comment: For example: $$\left.-\frac x{n\pi}\cos n\pi x\right|_{-1}^1=-\frac1{n\pi}\left(1\cos n\pi -(-1)\cos(-n\pi)\right)=-\frac1{n\pi}\left(\cos n\pi+\cos n\pi\right)=...\text{see?}$$

Comment: how did you get (-1) infront of cos? its not xcos(n*pi*x) is it? or is it the same thing??? this is extremely confusing :/ since the fraction is the only thing with x right? except for cos which have it in the paranthesis or something

Comment: @gger234, that's the way definite integrals (Riemann integrals) are done! This should be easy for you if you're dealing with Fourier series...

Comment: I got (-1/n*pi) *cos(pi*n) - (1/n*pi) * cos(-n*pi) idk if thats the same thing that you wrote?

Comment: yeah man, I see just wondering if you wrote it on a different form than what I got or something?

Comment: Now that you changed it, yes @gger234: what you wrote there is the same I did write....why do you have to ask this, though?